# Displaying and appending hidden child block to overlay from each list item

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery, overlay

I have an ordered list, basically every child  element is supposed to call the overlay and display and  list that is hidden by default, I did everything right I belive, but now when I click the button is displaying the same hidden div over and over, not the child of the button I am clicking, I have created a jsFiddle http://www.jsfiddle.net/aR7va/1/ I will apreciate any help.

Comment: Hi I recommend you to check your HTML in http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input you should not use an ul element inside an a element

Answer (score 0):

See updated code here: http://jsfiddle.net/aR7va/6/

The problem with your original was you were searching for just `$('.user-comment-list')`, which was finding all four of those content blocks and adding them to the overlay container. The updated code only searches for that class inside the  element. (As suggested in a comment, having a UL nested in an A isn't valid code, so you might want to look at changing that.) Also, I added a line to empty the overlay_content_inner each time, or the content just gets appended to the end when you click multiple buttons.

```
$('.my-list li .button').click(function(){
    var button = $(this);
    overlay_content_inner.empty();
    overlay.fadeIn(300,function(){
        button.find('.user-comment-list').css({"display":"block"}).appendTo(overlay_content_inner);
    });
});
btn_remove.click(function(){
    overlay.fadeOut(300,function(){});
});
```

**UPDATE**

I reorganized your code and simplified it a little. Instead of using `.appendTo()`, I changed it to `.html()`, which sets the innerHTML of the overlay_content_inner element to whatever is in the user-comment-list container for each link. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aR7va/22/

Comment: Hello all, I updated the ul nested list and everything works good, one  thing I notice is after clicking on all the buttons 1,2,3 and so on; to display the content, the content is not being displayed anymore, any ideas?  Here is the updated jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aR7va/19/